# How to do exceptional handling for a rest request with 2 actions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, httpresponse

I am creating Spring Boot application and have an endpoint which do 2 type of Actions on single request.

1st Action - Send Email
2nd Action - Send SMS

**Controller class**

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<Object> sendAction(Action act) {        
    try {
        actionService.createAlert(act);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Alert is generated successfully.", HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception occured while generating alerts. " , e);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Exception occured while generating alert.", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);            
    }
}
```

**Service Class:**

```
@Override
public void createAlert(Action act) throws Exception {
    try {
    String isSuccess = emailService.sendEmail(act);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        smsService.sendSMS(act,"Email Failed"); // Is this correct way? 
    }
    smsService.sendSMS(act, "Email Success");        
}
```

In this case, I am not able to distinguish to client whether both email and sms were succesful or just SMS.

How should I handle this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when sms should be sent?

Comment: it should be sent after email or even after email failed. I want to know how can i make client to distinguish this

Comment: What is the main task of sendAction()? Meaning which of the four success/failure combinations for e-mail and SMS mean overall success and which ones failure? is it enough to inform the client-side end user about the failure mode (error text), or does the client software need to respond differently to the possible failure modes (response object)?

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff yes, there are all 4 possible conditions. I need to send proper mode to client via text. I can do it via getting success response from both email/sms service in controller. but is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Let your alert services

```
static class MailException extends Exception {}
static class SMSException extends Exception {}

static void mailService_send(String message) throws MailException {
    if(message.length() > 5)
        throw new MailException();
}

static void smsService_send(String message) throws SMSException {
    if(message.length() > 5)
        throw new SMSException();
}
```

then, for your `sendAction` request define a response, e.g.

```
@ToString // lombok for simplicity
@AllArgsConstructor
static class SendActionResponse {
    boolean mailSent;
    boolean mailFailbackSMSSent;
    boolean smsSent;
    List<String> messages;
}
```

your logic, populate the response with the information you want

```
static SendActionResponse sendAction(String mailMsg, String mailSmsFailBackMsg, String smsMsg) {
    boolean mailSent = false;
    boolean mailFailbackSMSSent = false;
    boolean smsSent = false;
    List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        mailService_send(mailMsg);
        messages.add("Mail sent");
        mailSent = true;
    } catch (MailException e1) {
        try {
            smsService_send(mailSmsFailBackMsg);
            messages.add("Mail failure, failback sms sent");
            mailFailbackSMSSent = true;
        } catch (SMSException e2) {
            messages.add("Mail failure, failback sms failure");
        }
    }

    try {
        smsService_send(smsMsg);
        messages.add("Sms sent");
        smsSent = true;
    } catch (SMSException e3) {
        messages.add("Sms failure");
    }

    return new SendActionResponse(mailSent, mailFailbackSMSSent, smsSent, messages);
}
```

in this case, send mail and sms but, if mail fail try to send other sms too.

In this case, only 2^3 = 8 possibilities exists, running

```
String [] msg = new String [] {"short", "too long"};
for(String mail: msg)
    for(String mailFailback: msg)
        for(String sms: msg)
            System.out.println(sendAction(mail, mailFailback, sms));
```

you'll get

```
SendActionResponse(mailSent=true, mailFailbackSMSSent=false, smsSent=true, messages=[Mail sent, Sms sent])
SendActionResponse(mailSent=true, mailFailbackSMSSent=false, smsSent=false, messages=[Mail sent, Sms failure])
SendActionResponse(mailSent=true, mailFailbackSMSSent=false, smsSent=true, messages=[Mail sent, Sms sent])
SendActionResponse(mailSent=true, mailFailbackSMSSent=false, smsSent=false, messages=[Mail sent, Sms failure])
SendActionResponse(mailSent=false, mailFailbackSMSSent=true, smsSent=true, messages=[Mail failure, failback sms sent, Sms sent])
SendActionResponse(mailSent=false, mailFailbackSMSSent=true, smsSent=false, messages=[Mail failure, failback sms sent, Sms failure])
SendActionResponse(mailSent=false, mailFailbackSMSSent=false, smsSent=true, messages=[Mail failure, failback sms failure, Sms sent])
SendActionResponse(mailSent=false, mailFailbackSMSSent=false, smsSent=false, messages=[Mail failure, failback sms failure, Sms failure])
```

Comment: Thanks @josejuan. Let me try this